# Windows 7 repair installation on SSD creates huge pagefile making it unsuccessful

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, pagefile, repair-install

I have a system with 64 GB RAM with a bit corrupted Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 installation on a 128 GB SSD.

Current free space is about 64 GB so about 50% of the drive capacity. I don't use pagefile at all.

I'm trying to repair it via repair install but on the last checkmark where my files and programs are being restored it shows I got insufficient disk space.

After reverting to old Windows installation I've found it already created a 30 GB pagefile which probably didn't fit into my small SSD.

What is the solution for this ? Remove some RAM ?

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove seven RAM modules to get just 8 GB. Then it created just 8 GB pagefile. Moving pagefile to a different drive didn't helped !